# Integrating boost serialising into existing code

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have code of the form:

```
ODIstream &operator<<(ODIstream& vis, const Song &lyrics)
{
  vis >> doh;
  vis >> a;
  vis >> deer;
  vis >> a;
  vis >> female;
  vis >> deer;  
}
```

where ODIStream is an old deprecated class library's serialisation function and female is a container from a the deprecated class library.  These work together as they are build for each other.  I am tasked with updating this code and removing this library hence we get towards:

```
istream &operator<<(istream& vis, const Song &lyrics)
{
  vis >> doh;
  vis >> a;
  vis >> deer;
  vis >> a;
  vis >> female;
  vis >> deer;  
}
```

but female does not work with the ostream. When I change female to the stl::list that does not have a build in serialisation operator (the individual class elements do).

I was going to use boost: [serialisation code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) but I am not sure how to integrate the archive with the current code model.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Your mixing the input/output operators I would say.

Comment: ahem - ooops, fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

Note that serialization has a different goal then just streaming.

Serialization results in an *archive*. So, you wouldn't write to `ostream`, or read from `istream`. Instead, you'll write to an `oarchive` (text, binary, xml) or read from a corresponding `iarchive`.

Each archive will carry (considerable) archive headers. Therefore, factoring the archive as a detail inside the streaming operators seems like a bad idea, quick demo:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

struct Simplest    {
    int i;    

    template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*version*/) {
        ar & i;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Simplest const& data) {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
        oa << data;
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    Simplest a { 4215680 }, b { -42 };
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

This would result in

```
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 4215680
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 -42
```

all just to serialize... 2 integers.

Also, Boost Serialization was designed to handle archive errors. However, input streaming operators are usually expected to leave the input position if reading ('parsing') failed and care must be taken to leave the stream state in a proper state so the stream can still be used.

I suggest one of two approaches:

### 1. Use Boost Serialization all the way

Imagine a demonstrational `struct`

```
struct Demo
{
    int i;
    std::string truth;

    using Vars = std::map<std::string, double>;
    Vars vars;
};
```

Using simple serialize implementation and (and a helper just to do the debug printing):

```
int main()
{
    Demo a { 42, "LtUaE", { { "PI", 3.1415926 }, { "e", std::exp(1.0) } } };
    std::cout << "Debug : " << a << "\n";

    std::string const serialized = serialize(a);
    std::cout << "Serious serialization: " << serialized << "\n";

    // to parse back:
    Demo roundtrip = deserialize(serialized);
    std::cout << "Parsed back: " << roundtrip << "\n";
}
```

we get

```
Debug : 42;LtUaE;PI;3.14159;e;2.71828;
Serious serialization: 22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 42 5 LtUaE 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 PI 3.1415926000000001 1 e 2.7182818284590451
Parsed back: 42;LtUaE;PI;3.14159;e;2.71828;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40faef5cc925ae7a)**

One big win here is that it's easy to get binary streaming: [Live On Coliru **too**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dea0ae5df14c39f3):

```
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

struct Demo
{
    int i;
    std::string truth;

    using Vars = std::map<std::string, double>;
    Vars vars;

    template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*version*/)
    {
        ar & i;
        ar & truth;
        ar & vars;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Demo const& demo)
    {
        os << demo.i << ';' << demo.truth << ";";
        for (auto& e : demo.vars)
            os << e.first << ";" << e.second << ";";
        return os;
    }
};

static std::string as_hex(std::string const& binary)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (unsigned ch: binary)
        oss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << ch;

    return oss.str();
}

static std::string serialize(Demo const& data)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa << data;

    return oss.str();
}

static Demo deserialize(std::string const& text)
{
    std::istringstream iss(text);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(iss);
    Demo data;
    ia >> data;
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    Demo a { 42, "LtUaE", { { "PI", 3.1415926 }, { "e", std::exp(1.0) } } };
    std::cout << "Debug : " << a << "\n";

    std::string const serialized = serialize(a);
    std::cout << "Serious serialization: " << as_hex(serialized) << "\n";

    // to parse back:
    Demo roundtrip = deserialize(serialized);
    std::cout << "Parsed back: " << roundtrip << "\n";
}
```

### 2. Use Boost Spirit

Using the same Demo struct and

```
int main()
{
    Demo a { 42, "LtUaE", { { "PI", 3.1415926 }, { "e", std::exp(1.0) } } };
    std::cout << "Quick serialization: " << karma::format_delimited(karma::auto_, ';', a) << "\n";

    std::string const serialized = serialize(a);
    std::cout << "Serious serialization: " << serialized << "\n";

    // to parse back:
    Demo roundtrip = deserialize(serialized);
    std::cout << "Parsed back: " << karma::format_delimited(karma::auto_, ';', roundtrip) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Quick serialization: 42;LtUaE;PI;3.142;e;2.718;
Serious serialization: Demo{42;LtUaE;{{PI: 3.142}, {e: 2.718}}}
Parsed back: 42;LtUaE;PI;3.142;e;2.718;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71627d866d7cc472)**

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

struct Demo
{
    int i;
    std::string truth;

    using Vars = std::map<std::string, double>;
    Vars vars;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Demo, (int,i)(std::string,truth)(Demo::Vars, vars))

static std::string serialize(Demo const& data)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << karma::format(
            "Demo{" << karma::int_ << ';' << karma::string << ';' 
                << '{' 
                        << ('{' << karma::string << ": " << karma::double_ << '}') % ", " 
                << '}'
            << '}', data);

    return oss.str();
}

static Demo deserialize(std::string const& text)
{
    auto f(text.begin()), l(text.end());
    Demo parsed;
    if (qi::parse(f, l,
            "Demo{" >> qi::int_ >> ';' >> +~qi::char_(';') >> ';' 
            >> '{' 
                >> ('{' >> +~qi::char_(':') >> ": " >> qi::double_ >> '}') % ", " >> '}'
            >> '}', parsed))
    {
        return parsed;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Parse failed at '" + std::string(f,l) + "'");
}

int main()
{
    Demo a { 42, "LtUaE", { { "PI", 3.1415926 }, { "e", std::exp(1.0) } } };
    std::cout << "Quick serialization: " << karma::format_delimited(karma::auto_, ';', a) << "\n";

    std::string const serialized = serialize(a);
    std::cout << "Serious serialization: " << serialized << "\n";

    // to parse back:
    Demo roundtrip = deserialize(serialized);
    std::cout << "Parsed back: " << karma::format_delimited(karma::auto_, ';', roundtrip) << "\n";
}
```

### **TL;DR**

Use Boost Serialization the way it was intended for quick win; you'll get

- more robustness for smaller effort
- more flexibility for smaller effort
- lower compiletimes

The benefits of Spirit would be:

- absolute control over serialization format
- easy to parse human-readable/writable formats
- header-only library